# Estimate the result file size of an image before re-sizing ( or with one re sizing)

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, sampling, image-compression

For example, I have an 1024*768 JPEG/PNG image. I want to estimate the size of the image which will be scaled down to 800*600, 640*480 ( total 32 dimensions ). Is there any algorithm to calculate the size without generating all the scaled images?

Or more simply re-size to one dimension and use the result values to estimate size for rest.

I have tried some sampling and i could't form a pattern.

Comment: Hi, compressed size depends on content in original image, amount of compression, dimension of output image. You are asking to estimate it using only last two factors. You can definitely find a range (maybe a wide range) of size mathematically. You need to go through JPEG or PNG compression standard for details and understand how compression algos are working.

Comment: thanks pervez, I am a newbie to law level image processing algorithms. please clarify how to estimate  content in original image if it is possible .

Comment: Best way is you go through JPEG compression method. You estimate range keeping image content unknown variable. You need to understand how bits are saved and written in compact way. Just google or kick-start here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mgm/Final%20Report.pdf

Comment: in JPEG is used combination of DCT and Huffman encoding so you need space for: 1. JPEG header 2. DCT matrices `~= xs*ys*quality` xs,ys are resolution of image and quality is `0-1` factor 95% means 0.95 3. these DCT matrices are reorded (image is divided to usually 8x8 pixel areas so each has its own matrix)  and huffman encoded. so the top size is when no Huffman entropy encoding is present and the low is dependent on the content (how many of unfiltered frequencies are present in image) so you can use some average ratio value if you have common type images ...

Comment: so if you got one scale encoded you can deduce the rest if JPEG is used more or less accurately. you just do some research and measure the ratio vs scale of original image

Comment: Does any idea on png image compression